# How to use data attributes to store and select two prices on an option

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I'm trying to create a form where each option has two potential values. The user will first pick either "Low Price" (lp) or "High Price" (hp) and then pick either Type 1 or 2 which both have data attributes of "hp" and "lp". Ideally, by calling the data attribute with either the lp or hp value I should be able to select which price I want from Type 1 or 2 and have it displayed in the input labeled "Cost". Then the cost should be multiplied by the footage to find "Total". Unfortunately I can't get the data- attributes to work unless they are in the actual select tag instead of the individual option tags. Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here is a JS :

http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/Esr9f/3/

And here is the HTML:

```
<select id="pPost_P" class="pSelect">
    <option value="select">Price</option>
    <option value="lp">Low Price</option>
    <option value="hp">High Price</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select class="pSelect" id="pPost_D">
    <option value="select">Type</option>
    <option data-hp="5" data-lp="2" value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
    <option data-hp="9" data-lp="8" value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
</select>
<br/>    
<input id="pPost_C" placeholder="Cost" />
<br/>
<input id="pPost_F" class="pSelect" placeholder="Footage" />
<br/>
<input id="pPost_A" placeholder="Total" />
```

And here is the JS :

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class="pSelect"]', function () {
        var parts = $(this).attr('id').split("_"),
            service = parts[0],

            price = $("#" + service + "_P").val(),
            fee = parseFloat($("#" + service + "_D").data("'" + price + "'"), 10),
            cost = $("#" + service + "_C"),
            footage = parseFloat($("#" + service + "_F").val(),
            10),
            amount = '';
        if (isNaN(footage)) {
            total.val("Please enter Quantity");
        }

        if (!isNaN(footage) && (!isNaN(Number(fee)))) {
            amount = Math.ceil(footage * fee);
            total.val(amount);
            cost.val(fee);
        }
});
```

Comment: It's fairly trivial with jQuery. Read up on such methods as on() and append(). I think your terms are confused, though. An 'option', by definition, is a single entity.

Comment: Provide your attempt, if any...

Comment: If values come from database use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: isherwood - That's my point, is it possible to have a option in a select field have more than one value? I'm not worried about using the information for the second field as much as making an option with two distinct values.

Comment: A. Wolff - The only thing I could think of would be to use "value1= " and "value2= " lol.

Comment: Use `data-` attributes and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) for the second value.

Comment: Tushar Gupta, good point but unfortunately they don't. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger, that will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just going to leave this here in case someone has the same problem as I did. In short my biggest problem was that I was not selecting the actual option inside the select itself (at least not properly anyways) so once I fixed that it was just a matter of using data() with an argument of "percentage" that is the value of the selected option in the selector that chooses high or low price. Thanks for the help! Hope this helps someone else as well.

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class="pSelect"]', function(){
        var parts = $(this).attr('id').split("_"),
            service = parts[0],
            percentage = $("#" + service + "_P option:selected").val(),
            price = $("#" + service + "_D option:selected").data(percentage),
            footage = parseFloat($("#" + service + "_F").val(),10),
            fee =  Math.ceil(price * footage),
            cost = $("#" + service + "_C");

            cost.val(price);

        if(isNaN(footage)) {
            $("#" + service + "_A").val("Please enter Quantity");
        }

        if(!isNaN(footage) && (!isNaN(fee))) {
            $("#" + service + "_A").val(Math.ceil(fee));
            $("#" + service + "_C").val(fee);
        }
    });
```

An example of one of the options that has two different prices associated with it:
HTML

```
<option data-hp="63" data-lp="5">Type1</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#test").change(function(){
 var content =  $('#test option:selected').html();
 var valor = $('#test').val();   
 $("#second").append("<option value='"+valor+"'>"+content+"</option>");
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Zz5JL/

Comment: Thanks man! I was more concerned about getting two values for a single option in the select field but Blazemonger already answered that, but this helps too! Thanks!